# How do I get my program to open a window based of user input?

Tags: java, swing, static, non-static

I am fairly new to programming and I have been trying to program a very simple menu to allow a user to press a JRadioButton to select the mode of rock,paper,scissors (1 player or 2 player). My current code listens for which button is selected and then sets an int to 1 or 2. Then it takes that number and uses it to determine which window to open in the main method but I don't know what I should do because I can't reference a non static field to a static method.

This bit of my code sets the mode and then determines what window to open based off that int.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(p1.isSelected())
        mode = 1;
    else if(p2.isSelected())
        mode = 2;
}
public static void main(String args[])
{
    RPSMenu window = new RPSMenu();
    window.setBounds(300, 300, 400, 100);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setVisible(true);
    if(mode == 1)
    {
    Rps window1 = new Rps();
    window1.setBounds(300, 300, 400, 160);
    window1.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window1.setVisible(true);
    window.setVisible(false);
    }
    else if(mode == 2)
    {
    P2RPS window2 = new P2RPS();
    window2.setBounds(300, 300, 400, 150);
    window2.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window2.setVisible(true);
    window.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

if seeing my full code helps this is it:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class RPSMenu extends JFrame
implements ActionListener
{
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
JRadioButton p1, p2;
int mode;

public RPSMenu()
{
    p1 = new JRadioButton("   1 Player   ");
    p2 = new JRadioButton("   2 Player   ");

    ButtonGroup menu = new ButtonGroup();
    menu.add(p1);
    menu.add(p2);

    JButton go = new JButton("    Go!    ");
    go.addActionListener(this);

    Container m = getContentPane();
    m.setLayout( new FlowLayout());
    m.add(go);
    m.add(p1);
    m.add(p2);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(p1.isSelected())
        mode = 1;
    else if(p2.isSelected())
        mode = 2;
}
public static void main(String args[])
{
    RPSMenu window = new RPSMenu();
    window.setBounds(300, 300, 400, 100);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setVisible(true);
    if(mode == 1)
    {
    Rps window1 = new Rps();
    window1.setBounds(300, 300, 400, 160);
    window1.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window1.setVisible(true);
    window.setVisible(false);
    }
    else if(mode == 2)
    {
    P2RPS window2 = new P2RPS();
    window2.setBounds(300, 300, 400, 150);
    window2.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window2.setVisible(true);
    window.setVisible(false);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're trying to call non-static code from the static main method. The solution is not to do this, to use the main method just to set up your program and run it, but to call all of the other stuff within the class's code itself, either in its constructor or in an init method.

For instance, main could look like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  // to begin a Swing application in thread-safe mannter
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      Create your GUI class;
      MyGui myGui = new MyGui();
      myGui.init(); // initialize its fields, call your if blocks
      // etc...
    }
  });
}
```

Then in your `init()` method, you could show a dialog that gets the user's choice of number of players, and initialize and display your GUI in a non-static way.

Note that I would not swap windows as you're doing but rather create and show one JFrame and then swap ***views*** (here they'll be JPanels) using a CardLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class RPSMenu extends JFrame
implements ActionListener
{
/**
 * 
 */
/* it's typically considered bad practice to allow other classes to access a 
 * classes' variables, they should be accessed though a method that returns them*/
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JRadioButton p1, p2;
private int mode = 0;//you need to know if this has been set or if it is still at default value

public RPSMenu()
{
p1 = new JRadioButton("   1 Player   ");
p2 = new JRadioButton("   2 Player   ");

ButtonGroup menu = new ButtonGroup();
menu.add(p1);
menu.add(p2);

JButton go = new JButton("    Go!    ");
go.addActionListener(this);

Container m = getContentPane();
m.setLayout( new FlowLayout());
m.add(go);
m.add(p1);
m.add(p2);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
if(p1.isSelected())
    mode = 1;
else if(p2.isSelected())
    mode = 2;
}
public int getMode()
{
return mode;
}
public static void main(String args[])
{
RPSMenu window = new RPSMenu();
window.setBounds(300, 300, 400, 100);
window.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
window.setVisible(true);
while(window.getMode() == 0){/*wait for someone to press a button*/}
/* the non static type of mode should be accessed only from the object in which it is used
 * however, you could also just make it static and the program would also work but that's not your only problem*/
Rps window1 = null;
P2RPS window2 = null;//initilize these here so you can use them later
if(window.getMode() == 1)
{
//I am assuming this class and the other class below are your windows
window1 = new Rps();
window1.setTitle("Single Player RPS");
window1.setBounds(300, 300, 400, 160);
window1.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
window1.setVisible(true);
}
else if(window.getMode() == 2)
{
window2 = new P2RPS();
window2.setTitle("Two Player RPS");
window2.setBounds(300, 300, 400, 150);
window2.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
window2.setVisible(true);
}
window.setVisible(false);
while(window1 != null && window1.isVisible()){}
while(window2 != null && window2.isVisible()){}
}
}
```

You seem to have the idea that your program will automatically wait for input, but you have to come up with a way to do that on your own like how I did above, getting input through a window isn't like getting it from the console.